# Unexpected token when using different property name in object literal

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
let [circleTranslateX, circleTranslateY, circleScale] = [this.state.pan.x, this.state.pan.y, this.state.scale];

let circleTransform = [
    {circleTranslateX},
    {circleTranslateY},
    {scale: circleScale}
];
```

The above works fine, but if I change the line:

```
{circleTranslateX}
```

To:

```
{this.state.pan.x}
```

I get an `Unexpected token` error. Why is this so, if the code should be equivalent before destructuring?

Comment: `{circleTranslateX}` is shorthand for `{circleTranslateX: circleTranslateX}`

Comment: That's because of shorthand variable property declarations. `this.state.pan.id` is not a valid property identifier. It equates to `this.state.pan.id: this.state.pan.id` which is invalid syntax.

Comment: use `{x:this.state.pan.x}` (longhand) for many dots

Comment: Yup, that's it. Thanks everybody. Lots of downvotes so maybe I should delete the question. But, regardless, it helped me it might help others.

Comment: Probably down-voted because of the initial animation of the problem rather than its current code snippet form.  Down-voters may update their vote given the newer question format

Comment: @Pineda I hear ya. Gif animations are tough to index. But sometimes it's the best way to describe something when you're not sure what's going on. Glad Andrew Li edited my question, for everyone's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{circleTranslateX} 
// valid because it could be re-written as:
// {circleTranslateX: circleTranslateX}

{this.state.pan.x}
// would be akin to:
// {this.state.pan.x: this.state.pan.x}
// which isn't valid object initialisation
// because this.state.pan.x isn't a valid
// object key
```

Comment: I didn't even know this shorthand key/value existed. Is there a doc site I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: They've been mentioned in other answers but I'll add them here as they are the ones I found useful: [MDN Docs: Object Initialisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), [ES2015 Spec defintion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer)

Answer (score 3):

This is due to ECMAScript 2015's new object shorthand property declarations.  If you want to learn more about how this works, you can look at the language specification. Per the [language specification on Object Initializers, Section 12.2.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> ObjectLiteral :
>   { }
>   { PropertyDefinitionList }
>   { PropertyDefinitionList , }
> ```

Where *`PropertyDefinitionList`* is defined as:

> ```
> PropertyDefinitionList :
>   PropertyDefinition
>   PropertyDefinitionList , PropertyDefinition
> ```

And *`PropertyDefinition`* is:

> ```
> PropertyDefinition :
>   IdentifierReference
>   CoverInitializedName
>   PropertyName : AssignmentExpression
>   MethodDefinition
> ```

Thus, an object literal can contain property definitions, which are one of: *`IdentifierReference`* (the one that is relevant here), *`CoverInitializedName`*, *`PropertyName : AssignmentExpression`*, or *`MethodDefinition`*.

The new shorthand syntax is defined by the line where *`IdentifierReference`* is defined as one of the options for a *`PropertyDefinition`*. That means a property definition can just be an identifier reference and the property name will be string value of the reference and the property value, the result of evaluating the reference, see [Section 12.2.6.9](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation), second paragraph.

The problem comes in when you look at the definition of [identifiers, Section 12.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-identifiers):

> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> IdentifierReference : 
>   Identifier
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> Identifier :
>   IdentifierName but not ReservedWord
> ```

Where *`IdentifierName`* is just the identifier's name (variables name) and *`ReservedWord`* is a reserved keyword.

Now, to apply this to your current example. When you do `{circleTranslateX}`, it's perfectly valid because `circleTranslateX` is an *`Identifier`* (you destruct it earlier) and thus *`IdentifierReference`*. This matches the syntax for a property definition and is valid. It's comparable to:

```
{
    circleTranslateX: circleTranslateX
}
```

Which is also valid. On the contrary, your second example `{this.state.pan.x}` is invalid. This is because `this.state.pan.x` is not a valid *`IdentifierName`*, thus not a valid identifier or identifier reference. That means it does **not** match the syntax for an object literal and is thus invalid. It's not seen as an object by the engine so your attempt at an object literal results in an unexpected token. It's also comparable to (if it were even treated as an object):

```
{
    this.state.pan.x: this.state.pan.x
}
```

This is of course invalid because you can't have dots in property names.

Although, you could use [ECMAScript 2015 Compute: Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) which allow for expressions as property names if enclosed in square brackets:

```
{
    [this.state.pan.x]: this.state.pan.x
}
```

But I really see no point if you use array destructuring earlier to get `circleTranslateX`.

Further reading with [Object Initializers at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks for the lesson. And thanks for updating my original question with a more thoughtful, text-based description of the problem.

Comment: @JoshPinter No problem, I thought a little bit more explanation would help with the current answer.